# routerLinkActive with dynamic url doesn't work Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I have the following html template:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/views/' + typeParam + '/my-recently-updated'" routerLinkActive="active">some text</a>
```

When I click on that link I see item is selected but when I reload page (press F5) then I see no selected items.

views-routing.module.ts:

```
const viewsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ViewsComponent,
        children: [
            { path: ':type', component: ViewsWrapperComponent },
            { path: ':type/:view_name', component: ViewsWrapperComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(viewsRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ViewsRoutingModule { }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can u put your router module in question ?

Comment: @pc_coder ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it this way:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/views/' + typeParam + '/my-recently-updated'" 
    routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ __change_detection_hack__: typeParam }">some text</a>
```

as here [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18469#issuecomment-345436335)